# Is there a keyboard shortcut to create a folder in Chrome Bookmarks?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

I have about 9400 bookmarks on my computer and I like to organize them in folders. Right now I can only create a folder by right clicking and selecting Add a folder from the pop up menu.

Is there a way to create a folder via the keyboard?

Comment: According to [145 Shortcuts for Google Chrome](https://shortcutworld.com/Chrome/win/Google-Chrome_Shortcuts) the answer is no. You can probably write an [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script though.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> will add all existing tabs to a new folder. but apparently for some reason you can't add a single folder with just one tab open.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Did some testing, CTRL + Shift + D creates a new folder with all the Tabs that are currently open. Works both for Chrome and FireFox. In Vivaldi it opens the Download History.